# unique_ptr usage with tree-like data structures

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

Is modelling parent->child links in a tree-like data structure using unique_ptr viable if we are doing a lot of transformations which are likely to change these links?

Node class for the AVL tree I'm working on looks like this

```
struct Node final {
    Node *_parent{nullptr};
    std::unique_ptr<Node> _left{nullptr};
    std::unique_ptr<Node> _right{nullptr};
};
```

Child->parent links are implemented as raw pointers, as we don't expect the child to have a longer lifetime than its parent.

The rotate function looks like this

```
void rotate_subtree_left(node_type *old_root, node_type *new_root) noexcept {
    auto *old_root_parent = old_root->_parent;

    auto *new_root_left = new_root->_left.release();
    old_root->_right.release();
    old_root->_right.reset(new_root_left);
    if (old_root->_right != nullptr)
        old_root->_right->_parent = old_root;
    new_root->_left.reset(old_root);
    old_root->_parent = new_root;

    old_root->_balance_factor = 0;
    new_root->_balance_factor = 0;

    reset_subtree_parent(old_root_parent, new_root, old_root);
}

void reset_subtree_parent(node_type *subtree_parent, node_type *subtree_new_root, node_type *subtree_old_root) noexcept {
    subtree_new_root->_parent = subtree_parent;
    if (subtree_new_root->_parent != nullptr) {
        if (subtree_old_root == subtree_parent->_left.get()) {
            subtree_parent->_left.release();
            subtree_parent->_left.reset(subtree_new_root);
        } else {
            subtree_parent->_right.release();
            subtree_parent->_right.reset(subtree_new_root);
        }
    } else {
        _root.release();
        _root.reset(subtree_new_root);
    }
}
```

I'm passing raw pointers to the rotate function, but in order to change the parent->child links, I need to release() and reset() a lot of unique_ptrs.
Is there a better way to use smart pointers in this context?

Comment: You are changing ownership of `old_root`, having taken it by raw pointer. Should it instead be a `std::unique_ptr<node_type> &`? Are you releasing into the call here? Why is `old_root->_right` being released? You should probably be calling swap on the unique_ptrs

Comment: @Caleth, raw pointers passed into the call are obtained with .get(), so none of them are released at the point of the call.
When doing the left rotation old_root->_right == new_root.

Comment: Ok, so now you have two things owning `*old_root`, and no things owning `*old_root->_right` (the values before this call)

Comment: @Caleth, that's right, but the reset_subtree_parent() should fix that up, I'll attach that function as well.

Comment: `old_root->_right.release();` has leaked it

Comment: Tbh, smart pointers add nothing but complexity and frustration to an implementation of such a data structure. I'd argue it's because they model the wrong ownership. Nodes aren't owned by other nodes, they are owned by the tree as a whole.

Comment: @Caleth, `old_root->_right` and `new_root` are the same pointers. I'm releasing `old_root->_right`, but the raw pointer is still accessible through `new_root`.

Comment: I think they arent worth the trouble the not-so-smart pointers. Worsening perf and bloating the executable.

Comment: @user1095108 Where does `std::unique_ptr` worsen performance?

Comment: `old_root->_right.release();` will leak `old_root->_right`!

Comment: @Caleth I implemented some binary search trees and I observed that when running my examples. In the end I just used raw pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be passing around raw pointers and changing ownership in multiple steps. The much easier way is to use references to the actual pointer objects. N.b. this works even if you have the tree owning the nodes.

```
void rotate_subtree_left(std::unique_ptr<node_type> & old_root) noexcept {
    auto *old_root_parent = old_root->_parent;
    auto *new_root = old_root->_right.get();
    std::swap(old_root->_right, new_root->_left);
    std::swap(old_root, new_root->_left);
    new_root->_parent = old_root_parent;
    new_root->_left->_parent = new_root;
    if (new_root->_left->_right) {
        new_root->_left->_right->_parent = new_root->_left.get();
    }
    new_root->_balance_factor = 0;
    new_root->_left->_balance_factor = 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this makes more sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to be passing around raw pointers. Take a look at this Stack Review [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/251438) which details using `std::unique_ptr` in an AVL Tree implementation. It is a detailed walk-thru.

Based on that post, two quick take-aways related to the code you posted are that you should prefer default initialization such that the `Node` class could be written:

```cpp
struct Node final {
    Node *_parent{};
    std::unique_ptr<Node> _left;
    std::unique_ptr<Node> _right;
};
```

And, two, make use of `unique_ptr`'s automatic pointer moving functionality:

```cpp
subtree_parent->_left.release();
subtree_parent->_left.reset(subtree_new_root);
```

becomes:

```cpp
subtree_parent->_left.reset(subtree_new_root);
```

Comment: `.release()` does not take an argument. Did you mean `.reset()`? And if you did, did you check that it actually does the right thing, i.e., is it desired to delete the previously contained object?

Comment: @j6t, exactly `.reset(new_root)` does not work for me, because I mustn't delete the previously contained object.

Comment: @Mihailo The two code snippets are equivalent.

Comment: @RandomBits, isn't `.reset(new_root)` going to delete the old object?